# DateTimeFormatter.parseLocalDate throws UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, jodatime

The API for [parseLocalDate](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parseLocalDate%28java.lang.String%29)  says it will throw `UnsupportedOperationException` "if parsing is not supported". What does it mean by 'if parsing is not supported'? I'm looking through the source and can not find anywhere that throws `UnsupportedOperationException`. Has anyone ever been in a scenario where this exception was thrown from calling `parseLocalDate`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[DateTimeFormatter](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) have two usages:

- print dates;
- parse dates;

When you create [DateTimeFormatter instance](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#DateTimeFormatter%28org.joda.time.format.DateTimePrinter,%20org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParser%29), you pass to it [DateTimePrinter](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimePrinter.html) and [DateTimeParser](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeParser.html).

If your formatter has only **printer**, and you want **parse** date - `UnsupportedOperationException` will be thrown.

If your formatter has only **parser**, and you want **print** date - `UnsupportedOperationException` will be thrown.

**Example**

```
  DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatter(new DateTimePrinter()
  {
     // implements all abstract methods         
  }, null); // this instance has printer and hasn't parser
  formatter.print(new DateTime()); // works well
  formatter.parseDateTime("datetimestring"); // throws exeption
```

Comment: Ah good to know, thank you. It looks as though `org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern(String)` will always return a `DateTimeFormatter` with both a printer and a parser; so a `DateTimeFormatter` retrieved via `forPattern` should not ever throw `UnsupportedOperationException` correct?

Comment: Moreover, note that there are two similar instance methods:  `ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime()` and `ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser()`. If you used the latter and try for `.format(dateTime)`, you get this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to asnwer this just because I want to call out [@membersound](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1194415/membersound) comment to [@Ilya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1143825/ilya) answer as it was what was wrong with my code. Basically my team inherited some legacy code and who ever wrote the serializer for Joda DateTime set the formatter using `ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser()` instead of `ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime()`.

It especially confused me because the only error I saw at first was not an `UnsupportedOperationException`, but was instead logged as `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Printing not supported`, which I had a hard time finding when Googling it (as it was likely a recapturing of the actual error). I hope that helps someone else who spent maybe a little too long trying to figure out what was wrong like I did.